# How can I exit Appium(node) correctly for don't restore Appium window on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, applescript, appium, kill

I launch Appium server on Mac with:

```
open -a Terminal -n; osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
do script "appium -p 5677 -bp 1234"
end tell'
```

(open new terminal, and start Appium, Appium will open new window, but PID is new terminal's PID.)

and when Appium need to re-open, I'm using the following three steps:

1. kill Appium(node):

   ```
   killall node
   ```

   (I think this step node don't exit correctly, will restore when next time call Appium.)
2. Tell terminal exit:

   ```
   osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
   do script "exit"
   end tell'
   ```
3. Kill terminal(close terminal window):

   ```
   kill XXXXX (<-PID of second terminal)
   ```

When I run Appium with:

```
open -a Terminal -n; osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
do script "appium -p 5677 -bp 1234"
end tell'
```

it launches 2 Appium windows (1 is new window, and 1 is restore by system).

How can I exit Appium(node) correctly for don't restore Appium window?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using an osascript in Terminal to run a script in Terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's clean your code up:

1. ```
    open -a Terminal -n; osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
    do script "appium -p 5677 -bp 1234"
    end tell'
   ```

   can become:

   ```
   Appium -p 5677 -bp 1234 &
   ```
2. ```
    killall node
   ```

   might be better as:

   ```
   pkill -i Appium
   ```
3. ```
    Tell terminal exit:
    osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
    do script "exit"
    end tell'
   ```

   should just be:

   ```
   exit
   ```

Comment: Because I need to print Appium log on other terminal, now I launch new terminal and put Appium in background, thank you so much!